# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln n!}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n!}.$$ It is equal to 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n + \ln(n-1) +...+ ln(2))}.$$ But now what should I do to prove that it converges? (I have tried root test and ratio test.)

Comment: As an aside, see [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that : $n! = 2\times 3 \times \cdots \times n \ge 2^{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 2$. Consequently, we have for all $n\ge 2$
$$ 0 \le \frac{1}{n\ln(n!)}\le \frac{1}{n(n-1)\ln 2}. $$
Finally, you can conclude by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

We may also use the fact that $\log x$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence:
$$ \log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k)\geq n\cdot\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right) = n\cdot\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\tag{1}$$
and:
$$0\leq \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\log(n!)}\leq \frac{\zeta(2)}{\log(3/2)}.\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The main idea
is that
$\log(n!)
> c n( \log (n)+d)
$
for some positive real $c$
and real $d$
(which may be negative).
This means that
$\dfrac1{n \log(n!)}
< \dfrac1{cn^2 (\log n+d)}
$
which converges by any test you 
want to use.

A simple estimate,
which is good enough:

$\log(n!)
=\sum_{k=1}^n \log k
\ge\sum_{k=n/2}^n \log k
\ge\sum_{k=n/2}^n \log (n/2)
\ge(n/2) \log (n/2)
$.